# Drawing arrows between two points

Tags: qgis

I would like in QGIS to draw an arrow between two points that share the same id in the field ('globalid'). The goal is two show with an arrow where I want to move a point.
I have one layer name "RDP" ('globalid','to_move','moved') with all my entities and another one, which is a copy of the layer "RDP", that is called "RDP_moved" ('globalid','to_move','moved') with a filter on "moved" is 'yes'.

globalid: text
to_move: yes or no
moved: yes or no

Edit:
I succeeded to have the result I wanted with that function with the virtual layer and by creating a new layer with only the point where I wanted them (RDP_moved) and deleting those points of RDP_TVX:

```
select RDP_TVX.globalid, RDP_moved.globalid, makeline(RDP_TVX.geometry, RDP_moved.geometry) as geometry
from RDP_TVX, RDP_moved
where RDP_TVX.globalid = RDP_moved.globalid
```

Is it possible to use the geometry generator in the symbology instead of the virtual layer and use only one database from different layer with filters?

The data:

[image: the data, left layer RDP_TVX and left RDP_moved]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, your datastructure is not clear to me. Provide sample data (it's always cumbersome to rebuild the data you already have) and/or screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added a data sample.

Comment: You should share the data as file, not screenshot. Upload the file to a cloud and share the link here